# How do I get my chat filter bot to detect spaces in swear words, but not block words that have bad words in them such as "class"?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a chat filter bot to block swear words in Discord servers, and it works great, but people can easily bypass it by putting spaces in it. I had finally fixed this issue, but it blocks words that have bad words in them, such as "class". Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import string
import re
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'as-')

with open("badwords2.txt") as file:
    bad_words = file.read().splitlines()

def check_if_allowed(text):

    allowed_characters = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase #creates a string containing all upper- and lower- case letters.

    allowed_characters += "1234567890" # adds digits to the string

    if character not in allowed_characters: #checks if the character is in the set of allowed characters, and returns false if not
        return False

    return True #returns true if every character in the input is allowed
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):    
    clearMessage = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', message.content).lower()
    clearMessage = clearMessage.replace(" ","")

    for bad_word in bad_words:
        if bad_word in clearMessage:
            t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:   Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
            t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
            await message.channel.send(embed=t)
            await message.delete()
            return

    if not check_if_allowed(message.content):
        t = discord.Embed(color=0x039e00, title="Message Removed", description=":x:  Please do not swear. Swearing can result in a mute or ban.")
        t.set_footer(text="DM TheSuperRobert2498#2498 for bot suggestions.")
        await message.channel.send(embed=t)
        await message.delete()
        return


client.run('TOKEN')
```

All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you allow punctuation?

Comment: I think this is just a simple regex issue. Honestly, you should probably [stay away from regexes](https://xkcd.com/1171) whenever possible.

Comment: Can someone help me further with this?